# How to attack Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem if the first element in the superincreasing series is too small?

Tags: public-key, modular-arithmetic, attack, knapsack

In *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* Jeffrey Hoffstein et al. claim that "It turns out that if $r_1$ is too small, then there are easy attacks, so we must insist that $r_1>2^n$." Here $r_1$ is the first element of the superincreasing series used in the Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem before it is disguised with modular arithmetic and $n$ is the number of elements in the series. Does anyone have information on how these attacks might work or a basic explanation of why too small $r_1$ is unsafe?

Comment: Would you mind add / linking a description of the Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem? At least to me it's unknown and I'm quite sure the same applies to quite a few others here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's begin with a short description of the [Merkle-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) knapsack scheme. The private key is a superincreasing sequence of $n$ elements $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$, along with a secret element $W$ and $N$, with $W$ invertible modulo $N$. A superincreasing sequence is a sequence in which every element is greater than the sum of its predecessors:
$$
b_i > \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} b_j \,.
$$

The public key is the vector $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, where $a_i = W b_i \bmod N$. To encrypt a message, the sender splits the message into individual bits $m_i$, and calculates the encrypted message to be
$$
c = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i a_i \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n m_i b_i W \,.
$$

Decryption begins by multiplying $c$ by $W^{-1}$ modulo $N$, cancelling out the contribution of $W$, and then solving the subset sum for the known superincreasing sequence.

We can break the scheme by recovering either $W$ or $N$. The following simple attack is described in [Galbraith](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch19a.pdf)'s book. Suppose $b_1$ is small—much smaller than $2^n$. Then it is likely that $b_2$ is also similarly small, and we have the interesting property:
$$
\begin{align*}
  a_1b_2 &\equiv a_2b_1 \pmod{N} \\
  Wb_1b_2 &\equiv W b_2 b_1 \pmod{N}\,,
\end{align*}
$$
and therefore $a_1b_2 - a_2b_1$ is guaranteed to be a small multiple of $N$. By bruteforcing $b_1$ and $b_2$, we can recover a short list of candidate $N$, which we can then confirm by trying to recover $W = a_1/b_1 \pmod {N}$ and verify if this $W$ applies to the other $a_i, b_i$ as well. This suggests that $b_i$ should be at least $2^{n/2}$ in size.

This is not the only attack when $b_1$ is small. [Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/knapsack.survey.pdf) described another two, including the famous [Shamir](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d92/b96b8df5b7b1e1b6ec114d20e0ee22c25979.pdf) attack. There are also very relevant lattice attacks on Merkle-Hellman, but those are already seem to be described in Hoffstein et al.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to ask one thing: what happens when $b_1$ and $b_2$ are chosen so that $a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1 = 0$ (equality, not only modulo $N$)? Is there any way to recover (candidates for) $M$ in this case?

Comment: As far as I can tell the attack does not work in that case. But it has been a long time since I looked at this, so I could be missing something difference that could apply in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought so.